# Settle stocks on the same day [T] instead of [T+2/3]

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, stock-exchanges, settling-and-clearing

Is it possible to have same day settlement on the stock markets by using more efficient processes and technology?

I know that the T+3 settlement was earlier replaced by the T+2 settlement process. Can we improve it further to settle stocks the same day? And if yes, what are the challenges and problems that need to be addressed?

Comment: For that matter, why not settle instantly?

Comment: While an interesting question, this doesn't strike me as a personal finance.

Answer (score 1):

Some firms are already pushing toward T+0.

At one broker, when users  trade with other in house accounts, settlement is T+0.

Another broker offers T+1 settlement on some stocks so that when assigned on a covered call, one can buy new shares at current price, avoiding an assignment on the original shares which have a large capital gainand would therefore incur a larger tax bite.

Nearly 100 years ago, stock settlement was T+1 and rose to as  much as T+5 some  fifty years ago.  T+1 might be feasible again.

Comment: That last sentence is interesting... what made it rise up so steeply 50 years ago?

Comment: @Michael See: http://jpkoning.blogspot.com/2017/09/the-siren-call-of-t0-or-real-time.html

Comment: @MorrisonChang But don't the benefits outweigh the costs right now with all the advancements in technology? As mentioned in the post, Moscow used to have T+0 day settlement earlier, which means technology or cost is not the bottleneck here. So why haven't we already shifted yet? I would like to highlight one of the comment from the above post here: **_What work? Are physical stock certificates involved at some level? Isn't this all electronic?_**

Comment: @Sundeep Institutional processes have built up around existing rules which means change becomes harder. In the US brokers only moved to T+2 in 2017 from [T+3 which was enacted in 1995](https://ibkr.info/article/2930), so T+2 is already taking advantage of "paperless work". The settlement systems are mostly operating in batch mode working overnight between trading days. T+0 means processing during the day which isn't what the systems are designed for and would need change($$). See [What exactly happens during a settlement period?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/68052/14319) for more detail.